# Would this fridge fit in this space with required clearance?

Tags: refrigerator, confined-space

What is the best way to determine if a fridge of certain dimension will fit into a set space?

I have a inward kitchen cabinet space for a fridge which is 37" wide and 70.2" high. I figured it should have some margin, so in my mind the ideal dimension of a fridge should be around 34" wide, 69" tall, and 31" thick (but thickness isn't an issue).

However, after looking at the internet, I would like to get [this fridge](https://www.costco.ca/LG-36-in.-27.9-cu.-ft.--French-Door-Refrigerator-with-Slim-SpacePlus-Ice-System.product.100387255.html). Its dimension is 35.75" wide, 68.38" tall, and 33.75" thick. Does it look like it will fit in the space mentioned on paper? Is there another way to really be sure?

Comment: No I am asking if there should be a recommended margin/space in between the fridge and the closest enclosure, for safety, ventilation, or other purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just our luck. They provide [a handy-dandy manual](https://www.costco.ca/wcsstore/CostcoCABCCatalogAssetStore/Attachment/9001011-Product-Manual-EN.pdf) on the page you linked to, and here's what it tells us on page 15:

> Too small of a distance from adjacent items may result in lowered freezing capability and increased electricity consumption charges. Allow at least 24 inches (610 mm) in front of the refrigerator to op en the doors, and **at least 2 inches (50.8 mm) between the back of the refrigerator and the wall**.

This corresponds with my personal experience, wherein the only things that really matter are door clearance and a bit of space behind for warm air to circulate via convection. Whether that gap vents out the side or top isn't terribly important in most homes.